# How to Filter DataTable based on the Dictionary Keys?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, datatable

I am trying to filter the `DataTable` based on the `Dictionary` Keys using below `Linq`..

```
dtCartItems = dtCartItems.AsEnumerable()
                                .Where(c => _DicItemsInCart.All(kv => c.Field<string>("Circuit_Id") == kv.Key.ToString()))
                                .CopyToDataTable();
```

This Linq query working properly if `Dictionay` Conatins only one record (for one `key,value` pair record) but it shows exception (`The source contains no DataRows.`) when `Dictionary` has more than one row.

What changes needs to be done in above Linq query to get the expected filtered DatatTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`All()` returns only true if the provided function is true for every element in the collection. In your example only the items from `dtCartItems` get selected which have a `Circuit_Id` matching **all** keys in `DicItemsCart`.

I think you want to match **any** key in the dictionary.

```
dtCartItems = dtCartItems.AsEnumerable()
                         .Where(c =>
                             _DicItemsInCart.Any(kv =>
                                 c.Field<string>("Circuit_Id") == kv.Key.ToString()))
                         .CopyToDataTable();
```